# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V

Tags: eclipse, maven, jar, dependencies, slf4j

I get this error when I run my project with Tomcat 8.5 server in Eclipse:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.info(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:159)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:270)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4792)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5256)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1421)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1411)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My dependencies in **pom.xml** about **slf4j** are these:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
```

And when I run **'mvn dependency:tree'** in my project this is the result:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat8-maven-plugin:jar:3.0-r1756463 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat8-maven-plugin:3.0-r1756463: Plugin org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat8-maven-plugin:3.0-r1756463 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat8-maven-plugin:jar:3.0-r1756463 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
[INFO]
[INFO] -----------------< GestionPracticas:GestionPracticas >------------------
[INFO] Building GestionPracticas 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat8-maven-plugin:jar:3.0-r1756463 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat8-maven-plugin:3.0-r1756463: Plugin org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat8-maven-plugin:3.0-r1756463 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat8-maven-plugin:jar:3.0-r1756463 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
[WARNING] The POM for org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.6.RELEASE is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ GestionPracticas ---
[INFO] GestionPracticas:GestionPracticas:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.12:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:5.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:jar:5.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-core:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-api:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.5.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-servlet:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-jsp:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tiles:tiles-template:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:6.0.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:jar:4.2.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.mchange:c3p0:jar:0.9.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.mchange:mchange-commons-java:jar:0.2.3.4:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.0:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- displaytag:displaytag:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.lowagie:itext:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:jcl104-over-slf4j:jar:1.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- taglibs:standard:jar:1.1.2:provided
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.764 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-17T23:51:28+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I don't know if I'm missing something or I don't know how to interpret the information. I also tried with the version 1.7.5 for slf4j-log4j12 but I get the same thing.

**EDIT:**

`org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog` appears in 2 different paths:

- `C:\Users\...\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.5.8\jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.8.jar`
- `C:\Users\...\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jcl104-over-slf4j\1.4.2\jcl104-over-slf4j-1.4.2.jar`

But I don't know which one fails and how I can avoid loading a jar when updating the maven project from the pom.xml for not getting the error when I run Tomcat

Answer (score 1):

Try clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> and enter `org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog` and `org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger` on eclipse, and then you can detect name and version of jars including them. I think you have multiple jars including them and one of them is unintentionally loaded and causes `NoSuchMethodError`.

**EDIT:**

You may be able to avoid the error to add the `<exclusions>` tag:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>displaytag</groupId>
    <artifactId>displaytag</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl104-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I edited the post with new info but I still don't know how to solve this

Comment: @atila665 Please check the additional comment of my answer and try it.

Answer (score 0):

DisplayTag is super old (but I use it too) and depends on old jars.  I think jcl-over-slf4j has all the functionality of jcl104-over-slf4j so you don't want both in your app.  Try this...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>displaytag</groupId>
    <artifactId>displaytag</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jcl104-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```